# two java.lang.NullPointerException errors

Tags: java

I am actually getting three java.langNullPointerException errors, but two of them are the same  so if I fix one I'll fix the other.

I'm trying to make a Game Class to pass a gameTest

Here is the code for my Game Class

```
public class Game implements CribbageConstants {

    private Player player1, player2;
    private boolean player1Deals;
    private Game game;

    /**
     * No argument constructor - set default values for Game
     */
    public Game() {
        player1 = player1;
        player1 = player2;
        player1Deals = true;



    }

    // convenience constructor
    public Game(Player player1, Player player2) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
        this.player1Deals = true;

    }

    //mutator
    public void setPlayer1(Player player1) {
        this.player1 = player1;

    }

    public void setPlayer2(Player player2) {
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    public void setPlayer1Deals(boolean player1Deals) {
        this.player1Deals = player1Deals;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    //utility methods
    public Player getPlayer1() {
        return player1;
    }

    public Player getPlayer2() {
        return player2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the player1Deals
     */
    public boolean isPlayer1Deals() {
        return player1Deals;
    }

    /**
     * @return the game
     */
    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }
}
```

I'm getting one NullPointerException on line 86 of the following code:

```
//79    public void testSetPlayer1() {
//80        System.out.println("setPlayer1");
//81        Game instance = new Game();
//82        Player p1 = new Player("Jim");
//83        p1.setHand(hand1);
//84        Player p2 = new Player("George");
//85        p2.setHand(hand2);
//86        assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
//87        instance.setPlayer1(p1);
//88        assertEquals("Jim", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
    }
```

I'm getting one NullPointerException on my testNoArgConstructor (line 54)

```
//51    public void testNoArgConstructor() {
//52       System.out.println("Game");
//53       Game instance = new Game();
//54       assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
//55       assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer2().getName());
//56       assertEquals(true, instance.isPlayer1Deals());
//57   }
```

Comment: dont forget to create and object u use the keyword `new` u just dont assign anyhow. in the default constructor just assign those 2 players to `new Player();` and see how that might help

Answer (score 1):

You've not set variable `player1` before `instance.getPlayer`()`

```
//79    public void testSetPlayer1() {
//80        System.out.println("setPlayer1");
//81        Game instance = new Game();
//82        Player p1 = new Player("Jim");

            instance.setPlayer1(p1);

//83        p1.setHand(hand1);
//84        Player p2 = new Player("George");
//85        p2.setHand(hand2);
//86        assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
//87        instance.setPlayer1(p1);
//88        assertEquals("Jim", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
    }
```

You've same problem in both the case.

```
//51    public void testNoArgConstructor() {
//52       System.out.println("Game");
//53       Game instance = new Game();

           instance.setPlayer1(new Player("Player One");
//54       assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());

           instance.setPlayer2(new Player("Player Two");
//55       assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer2().getName());
//56       assertEquals(true, instance.isPlayer1Deals());
//57   }
```

If you can't edit your test case, you can try default values for variables in `Game`

```
public Game() {
        player1 = new Player("?");
        player1 = new Player("?");
        player1Deals = true;



    }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer "Fingers" :/ !!

Comment: My problem is that I'm not allowed to edit the gametest.  I can only make changes to the class

Comment: @user2827773 So, either your tests or your code are wrong.  Have you tried creating "dummy" players in the default constrcutor...

Comment: @user2827773 You can have default players with name as "?". Check out updated answer.

Comment: Bingo! That fixed it.  Now I just have a toString error I'm trying to fix.  I haven't coded the toString yet.  I'll see if I can get it sorted out

Comment: @user2827773 Great :). It would be better if you close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Game instance but you have never instantiated any players so when you use `getPlayer1()`, there is no player.

So call `instanse.setPlayer1(new Player());` after you create teh game but before you reference the `getPlayer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a short walk down a desk check...

```
Game instance = new Game();
// instance.player1 and instance.player2 are null...

Player p1 = new Player("Jim");
p1.setHand(hand1);
Player p2 = new Player("George");
p2.setHand(hand2);

// instance.player1 and instance.player2 are still null...
// Break here...
assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
instance.setPlayer1(p1);
```

If you were to change you code to look more like...

```
Game instance = new Game();

Player p1 = new Player("Jim");
p1.setHand(hand1);
Player p2 = new Player("George");
p2.setHand(hand2);

instance.setPlayer1(p1);
assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
```

You might have more success...

And this...

```
Game instance = new Game();
assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer1().getName());
assertEquals("?", instance.getPlayer2().getName());
assertEquals(true, instance.isPlayer1Deals());
```

Is a symptom of the same problem, both `instance.player1` and `instance.player2` are `null`

I "think" your confusion is steaming from...

```
public Game() {
    player1 = player1;
    player1 = player2; // Not sure if this is correct...
    player1Deals = true;
}
```

Assigning nothing to nothing is still nothing...

This is actually the same as saying...

```
public Game() {
    player1 = null;
    player1 = null;
    player1Deals = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getPlayer1()` function is a `Player` type, so you should use `p1.getPlayer1()`. You `instance` is a `Game()` type. And also, I think you function `getName()` should defined as a `Player` type.